Cache-optimized way to process collisions between all pairs of objects in two arrays
I am working on the hitbox collision system for a game. I have two arrays of convex objects that I need to check for collisions between objects in opposite lists (M hitboxes vs N hurtboxes). I am wondering, after reading the Data Oriented Design book, how I can approach this problem in an optimal way?
Each object is a convex hull of a set of spheres (I will use GJK for the collision). Assuming 32-bit scalars and 64-byte cache lines, I can fit 16 scalars per cache line, equivalently 4 spheres (X,Y,Z,R). Each object will additionally have a bounding sphere (these will be stored in separate arrays). Collisions between bounding spheres will form an initial broad-phase for the collision, providing pairs to check with GJK in a second narrow-phase.
Right now, I am guessing the optimal approach for the broad-phase is to process in cache-sized chunks (so 4 spheres at a time), and outside that just processing in a normal 2D for-loop setup:
for (int i = 0; i < M; i += 4)
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j += 4)
        {Process 4x4 tile of bounding spheres. On hit store (i,j) pairs for narrowphase}

I'm not sure what the best approach is for the narrow-phase though. Each object is likely to require probably a minimum of 2 cache lines, so I don't know if there's anything to gain by, for example, copying/moving the objects to adjacent locationsthe.

Not sure if it applies, but a database crossjoin algorithm I figured out uses Hilbert curve co-ordinates that ensures that MRU elements are paired. It means optimal reuse of entries from all inputs, in processor cache, memory and disk storage --- without needing to know anything about storage sizes. The approach works for more than two inputs. The Hilbert package written in 2000 by Doug Moore at Rice University ensures minimal cost to generate successive points on the curve.
There's a bit of clever in handling inputs of (initially) unknown size. Hth
